# VBA for Word: Add sub on event

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add this code to `ThisDocument` in my Word .docm file.

```
Sub AutoClose()
ActiveDocument.Saved = False
End Sub
```

The code prevents the "Do you want to save?" dialog from appearing. I only want to add this however after a certain click event in the document, because I also have `Save As` and `Save` disabled, and if I add all three, then I wouldn't be able to save the document myself. (In fact, I can't add all three, for that reason.)

If I add the above code only to be active after the last click event in the document however it should be fine, since then I can still save changes I make, as long as I haven't clicked that trigger at the end yet. Preventing people from closing and getting the "Do you want to save?" dialog at the end is the most important to me.

is there a way to write the above code to ThisDocument when another click event fires? Or put another way, is there any way to have a click event put the above code into effect?

Here's the sub at the end that I'd want to have trigger the above code to (activate? Be written? Be enabled? Be uncommented?)

```
Private Sub formatSaveB_Click()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mark3").Select
    Selection.Delete
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Format = wdFormatFilteredHTML
        .Show
End With

End Sub
```

So after that event happens, I want

```
Sub AutoClose()
    ActiveDocument.Saved = False
    End Sub
```

to be active in ThisDocument -- but not *before* that event.

Comment: Use a public boolean variable and use that to set the document saved state instead.

Comment: Please write an answer rather than editing your question

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer, just a slight correction to one word in my question. Explained in comments below, I guess I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatic access to the VBA project will need to be enabled if it isn't already.  However, to add the sub you described after the other code runs add this code to your sub:

```
ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString "Sub AutoClose(): ActiveDocument.Saved = False: End Sub"
```

That should do the trick.  You may have to tinker a little, I can't test fully because I'm in an environment where programatic access to the VBA project is disabled, but that should do what it sounds like you want to do.

Slight edit:  If you want to prevent the "Do you want to save changes you made ... " message when closing word you would need to do this:

```
ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString "Private Sub Document_Close(): ActiveDocument.Saved = True: End Sub"
```

Which will prevent that message from displaying when closing the document.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be writing it to ThisDocument, after adding your code, after that click event I now see `Sub AutoClose(): ActiveDocument.Saved = False: End Sub`. However it's not preventing the "Do you want to save?" dialog-- perhaps because the code isn't saved? I know sometimes it takes effect immediately, and other times you have to close and open the doc for things to work.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the code is saved - are you sure that this code suppresses that message?  If you want to prevent that message when you close the document you will need to use `Private Sub Document_Close()` and then use `ActiveDocument.Saved = True` to avoid that message.  But then the document will close without saving or prompting the user to save, so I hope that is what you intend.

Comment: When I added the AutoClose() code that I included in my post above, just as I have it there, then when I clicked to close the document, even if I had made edits, the document just closed, changes unsaved, with no "do you want to save" prompt. I think your/SOofWXLS's other idea is better also, just not getting it to work yet. I have to go to an appointment now but will mess around with this later today. Thx

Comment: I'm not sure how you're closing the document, but grabbing the close event should do it.  You could apply both though.

Comment: Sorry, yes the code that works is `ActiveDocument.Saved = True` (not False). I woke up with a wrenched neck and it was wrecking my concentration, clearly. I'm still not getting the variable version to work, but will keep trying. If I put in your second set of suggestions, verbatim, it still prompts to save. Whereas if I put just my first code sample at the top of the page, anywhere in the document, it closes without prompting (or saving). Which is what I want, but only after that last sub is run.

Comment: PS: Referring to closing by clicking the X at the corner of the page. I've also got save, and save as (either selecting those from the menu or using keyboard shortcuts) disabled right at the start, and those two pieces of code work fine.

Comment: Well if you're just closing the document, using the event `Private Sub Document_Close()` inside the `ThisWorkbook` module should get you the desired result if you're setting `ActiveDocument.Saved = True`

Comment: Also, ignore the variable method.  That was silly and won't work at all.  You don't have a macro running constantly so you can't retain a value in that public variable in that way.  I was thinking like a .Net programmer trying to do VBA for a second.  And not a very bright .Net programmer at that.  I really think the last line in my answer, as it is now, will get you the desired result.  I've tested it and it works for me anyway.

Comment: Okay that must be why it didn't work then ;) Thanks anyway. For the rest, your second suggestion yields "Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method". The first suggestion as I say inserts the line, but seems to have no effect.

Comment: Ok your second one does work, you just had a typo in it which I only spotted now. Perfect, thx.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  There is no such thing as a "VBCompotents"

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely follow your logic but I think what you're asking is something like this:

*ThisDocument module*

```
Public event1 As Boolean
Public event2 As Boolean

Sub AutoOpen()

event1 = False
event2 = False

End Sub
```

*Event Procedures*

```
Private Sub formatSaveB_Click()
    '// Event code here...
    event1 = True
End Sub

Private Sub otherEvent_Click()
    '// Event code here...
    event2 = True
End Sub
```

*Then in your final sub*

```
Sub AutoClose()
 '// Saved state only set to true if previous 2 events have been executed.   
    ActiveDocument.Saved = (event1 And event2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this but I'm not getting it to work. I think you understood what I was getting at, except I only needed one event procedure, not two. The `formatSaveB_Click()` is when I need it to change. If I include all you have here except only event1, not event2 -- it doesn't seem to put `ActiveDocument.Saved = False` into effect. Will keep messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in the event handler you want to disable the dialog, then test it when you exit. Note that you have to check for either the flag ***or*** if the document is already saved to avoid being prompted if the document actually has been saved but you haven't triggered formatSaveB_Click(). Assumes that `formatSaveB_Click()` is in ThisDocument.

In ThisDocument:

```
Private clicked As Boolean

Sub AutoClose()
    ActiveDocument.Saved = clicked Or ActiveDocument.Saved
End Sub

Private Sub formatSaveB_Click()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mark3").Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
            .Format = wdFormatFilteredHTML
            .Show
    End With
    'Set your flag here.
    clicked = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay adding this line from MattB did the trick, after I discovered that his suggestion had a typo, and I deleted the extra letter :)

```
ThisDocument.VBProject.VBCompontents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString "Private Sub Document_Close(): ActiveDocument.Saved = True: End Sub"
```

I was just pasting it in to try it like the others, and it had `VBCompontents` which I didn't spot until just now going over this again, and once I deleted the extra `t`, bingo.

Just what I needed. Thanks a bunch.